# add attachments to email in PHP without PEAR library

Tags: php, cakephp

how to insert attachments to email in PHP without pear library?

Comment: Using some other library like [SwiftMailer.](http://swiftmailer.org/)

Comment: @Pekka This should be an answer, not a comment ;)

Comment: You can also have a local copy of PEAR::Mail... It is not necessarily required to have it "installed" and added via include_path.

Answer (score 0):

It's preferable to use a library, but in case you only want to use mail you will have to add the content of your attachement in the headers with chunk_split(base64_encode()).

Here is an example:

http://www.geekology.co.za/blog/2009/06/sending-emails-with-attachments-using-php-mail-function/

BTW SwiftMail is an awesome email library:

http://swiftmailer.org/wikidocs/v3/tutorials/attachments

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is tagged CakePHP, you might want to use the [cakephp email component](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1638/Attachments). I can give some code if needed.